# XML entities not working with node-mapnik

Tags: mapnik, node-js

I'm not getting [XML entities](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/ManagingLargeXmlFiles) to work with node-mapnik. In the [changelog for 1.4.4](https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#144) I read:

"Mapnik now build with rapidxml/ptree xml parser rather than libxml2 (meaning no xincludes or entities are supported)".

Are there other ways of using variables or include other XML stylesheets in node-mapnik? Is it possible to configure node-mapnik to support XML entities and includes?